# Order of numpy orperations is not equal to logic (and also octave)?

Tags: python, numpy

Maybe this question should be strictly in the scipy-users, but I'll try here too.

So here is something which I discovered lately and is making me wonder.

I want to define a scalar which I call Net Absolute Mass Balance Error or in short NAMBE. 
This NAMBE is the absolute difference between a base vector and another vector, divided by the base vector and multiplied by a hundred, in pseudo-code notation:

```
NAMBE=sum(abs(a-b)/a)*100
```

When I do it in python, I decided to break the line into two lines so the code is more
readable:

```
>>> a=np.array([0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1])
>>> b=np.array([0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1])*2
>>> b
array([ 0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2])
>>> a-b
array([-0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1])
>>> s=np.sum(abs(a-b))
>>> s
0.5
>>> s/np.sum(a)
1.0
```

I thought the numpy does everything element wise so if I do it one line, I noticed the the result is different:

```
>>> s=np.sum(abs(a-b)/a)
>>> s
5.0
```

Now If I check myself on the data I have with a octave, I get different results:

```
octave:1> a=[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]
a =

   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000   0.10000

octave:2> b=a*2
b =

   0.20000   0.20000   0.20000   0.20000   0.20000

octave:3> sum(a)
ans =  0.50000
octave:4> sum(b)
ans =  1
octave:5> sum(a-b)
ans = -0.50000
octave:6> sum(abs(a-b))
ans =  0.50000
octave:7> s=sum(abs(a-b))
s =  0.50000
octave:8> s/sum(a)
ans =  1
octave:9> s=sum(abs(a-b)/a)
s =  1.0000
octave:10> s=sum(abs(a-b)/sum(a))
s =  1
```

Note that the is no difference in the output of 9 and 10 in Octave, although there is in Python ...
So, my question is:
Why is python is behaving like that ? Which one is right ? Octave or Python ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sum(a-b)/sum(a)` is not the same as `sum((a-b)/a)`.

Consider e.g. `a=[1,0]` and `b=[-1,1]`. Then `sum(a/b) == sum([-1,0]) == -1`, but `sum(a)/(sum(b) == 1/0` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: When I tell you that b can only have positive values ? I should have mentions that before. I understand the argumentation, but I think numpy should in this case behave like Octave.

Comment: Plus, I actually, tried your test case: here is the result:       >>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([1,0])
>>> b=np.array([-1,1])
>>> np.sum(a)/np.sum(b)
0
 As you can see - it yield 0 and not Inf !!! Python in this case behaves in very unintuitive way, while octave gives:                  octave:1> a=[1,0]
a =

   1   0

octave:2> b=[-1,1]
b =

  -1   1

octave:3> sum(a)/sum(b)
warning: division by zero
ans = Inf

Comment: @Oz123, that's a difference in handling errors like division by 0. Division by 0 is actually undefined so the answer isn't necessarily infinity. In numpy, it is set to 0. The default in numpy is to ignore floating point errors. You can change this though. For instance, if you use `np.seterr(all='warn')` then you will be warned about the division by 0. By the way, I would actually say that Octave is doing output 9 wrong. I'm guessing that instead of doing element-by-element division when dividing two vectors, it decides to divide one vector by the magnitude of the other.

Comment: The difference in division by zero is that python, as a general purpose language, and numpy by extension sets the type of an integer literal to an integer. If you use floating point numpy arrays then 1/0 will result in Infinity. In Octave, OTOH, integer literals are promoted to floats.